# Practical examples of MongoDB documents

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I would like to learn how to properly design MongoDB documents. I know about [MongoDB manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/) with special section about [document design](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/). Where can I find some practical examples of documents for social networks, cms sites, logging applications? Code that I can look into and learn from.

Thanks for your time and have a nice day!

Comment: This isn't specifically for document design, but there's also a cookbook on the MongoDB site: http://cookbook.mongodb.org/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please check this out if you really want to see a detailed approach from mongodb's creators; this is really good: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/ .

Answer (score 4):

[MongoDB](http://www.10gen.com/presentations) has some great talks with examples. I would particularly concentrate on the schema design talks.

Comment: Definitely worth watching some of the presentations so you not only see the schema used, but also get some insight into the reasons a particular schema was chosen.  A "good" schema can be highly dependent on your application and the common queries and updates it uses.

Answer (score 2):

I bought a book on Amazon titeled [MongoDB Applied Design Patterns](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920027041.do) from [Rick Copeland](http://blog.pythonisito.com/). It is a "short" book with practical use cases on how to use MongoDB. It describes practically how to use MongoDB in CMS, social networking, online gaming, ecommerce, etc... Exactly what I was looking for. :)